# JSF 2 Copyright symbol

Tags: java, jsf

I have following outputText:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{bean.copyrightText}"/>
```

This **copyrightText** is loaded from properties file (**bean** is Spring Bean):

```
server.copyrightText=&copy; &#169; 2016 some text goes here
```

Unfortunately copyright symbol is not redered correctly. Instead following string is rendered (IE, Chrome, Firefox):

```
&copy; &#169; 2016 some text goes here
```

When I add this symbol directly in Java then copyright symbol is rendered correctly:

```
res.append("\u00a9 ");
```

What can be the rootcause of this problem?

Comment: Symptoms tell a lot about the cause of the problem and inherently thus also the solution. Your *"is not rendered correctly"* statement is a really unclear description of the problem symptom and therefore unhelpful in understanding your problem. Describe detailed in developer's perspective what exactly happens instead.

Comment: Thanks, updated description.

Comment: So, either escape="false" doesn't seem to have any effect, or that "Spring Bean" is internally also escaping it, effectively making the text double-escaped? Try loading properties file via standard JSF <resource-bundle> facility instead, so we can exclude Spring from being the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use unicode characters in spring resource bundle´s. This should work:

```
server.copyrightText=\u00a9 2016 some text goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly **`&#169;`** in xhtml file for copyright symbol. It will not return reference error.

Reference link http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/rf-template.html